# Inline assembly inefficient procedure in Delphi using SSE2

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86, sse

I have a simple floating-point based operation that is always executed twice. So I've tried to translat it to SSE but it just fails. The high level language is Delphi, so as it doesn't support Intrinsics functions, I have to write the whole thing. 
Basically I just have parameter load/unload and some multiplications and addditions.:

```
Procedure TLP1Poly2.Process(Const _a1, _b1, _OldIn1, _OldIn2, _OldOut1, _OldOut2:     Double; Var Sample1, Sample2: Double);
Asm
  MOVLPD  XMM4, _a1
  MOVHPD  XMM4, _a1
  MOVLPD  XMM3, _b1
  MOVHPD  XMM3, _b1
  //
  MOVLPD  XMM0, [Sample1]
  MOVHPD  XMM0, [Sample2]
  MULPD   XMM0, XMM4
  //
  MOVLPD  XMM1, _OldIn1
  MOVHPD  XMM1, _OldIn2
  MULPD   XMM1, XMM4
  //
  MOVLPD  XMM2, _OldOut1
  MOVHPD  XMM2, _OldOut2
  MULPD   XMM2, XMM3
  //
  ADDPD   XMM0, XMM1
  ADDPD   XMM0, XMM2
  //
  MOVLPD  [Sample1], XMM0
  MOVHPD  [Sample2], XMM0
  //
  // which stands for twice this:
  // Sample:= Sample*a1 + oldinp*a1 + oldout*b1;
  // 
End;
```

but this procedure doesn't work, If I 'nop' everything between Sample1/Sample2 loading/saving it's ok but otherwise my filter is silent. What is the basic thing I don't get with SSE in this ?

Addenum:

old class class:

```
constructor TLP1.create;
begin
  oldfreq := -1 ;
end;
procedure TLp1.process(inp,Frq,SR :single);
begin
  if Frq<>oldfreq then
    begin
      a := 2* SR;
      t := Frq * _ppi;
      n := 1/ (a+t) ;
      b1:= (a - t) * n;
  a1:= t * n;
  oldfreq := frq;
    end;
   outlp   := (inp+_kd)*a1 + oldinp*a1 + oldout*b1;
   oldout  := outlp ;
   oldinp  := inp;
 end;
```

New class:

```
Procedure TLP2Poly2.SetSamplerate(Const Value: Single);
Begin
  If Value = FSamplerate Then Exit;
  FSamplerate := Value;
  UpdateCoefficients;
End;

Procedure TLP2Poly2.SetFrequency(Const Value: Single);
Begin
 If Value = FFrequency Then Exit;
  FFrequency := Value;
  UpdateCoefficients;
End;

Procedure TLP2Poly2.UpdateCoefficients;
Var
  a,t,n: Single;
Begin
  a := 2 * FSamplerate ;
  t := FFrequency * 2 * pi;
  n := 1/ (a+t) ;
  b1:= (a - t) * n;
  a1:= t * n;
End;

Procedure TLP2Poly2.Process(Var Sample1, Sample2: Double);
Var
  o1, o2: Double;
Begin
  o1 := Sample1;
  o2 := Sample2;
  IntProcess( a1, b1, OldIn1, OldIn2, OldOut1, OldOut2, Sample1, Sample2);
  OldOut1 := Sample1;
  OldOut2 := Sample2;
  OldIn1  := o1;
  OldIn2  := o2;
End;

Procedure TLP2Poly2.IntProcess(Const _a1, _b1, _OldIn1, _OldIn2, _OldOut1, _OldOut2:    Double; Var Sample1, Sample2: Double);
Asm
  MOVLPD  XMM4, _a1
  MOVHPD  XMM4, _a1
  MOVLPD  XMM3, _b1
  MOVHPD  XMM3, _b1
  //
  MOVLPD  XMM0, [Sample1]
  MOVHPD  XMM0, [Sample2]
  MULPD   XMM0, XMM4
  //
  MOVLPD  XMM1, _OldIn1
  MOVHPD  XMM1, _OldIn2
  MULPD   XMM1, XMM4
  //
  MOVLPD  XMM2, _OldOut1
  MOVHPD  XMM2, _OldOut2
  MULPD   XMM2, XMM3
  //
  ADDPD   XMM0, XMM1
  ADDPD   XMM0, XMM2
  //
  MOVLPD  [Sample1], XMM0
  MOVHPD  [Sample2], XMM0
End;
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't mean much.  What is this code?  What is it supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?  A bit more detail would be very helpful.

Comment: it's a LowPass filter, 1 Pole. the original code is put as comment at the end of the highlighted code. a1 and b1 are the coefficients, which are just the same as the original version of the filter.

Comment: What exactly Delphi procedure you want to translate? Your code remarks are insufficiency.

Comment: I think that the commented code is enough.

Comment: @az01: It doesn't matter if **you** think the commented code is enough if you want help here. If the "commented code is enough", use it to figure things out by yourself. If you want help here, and people ask for more information, give it to them (or delete your question). Being rude and uncooperative won't get you help. :)

Comment: As I can see your xmm asm function is OK and works!

Answer (score 6):

When writing assembler for Delphi, especially in 64 bit mode, you should always be aware of how parameters are passed. I never use the names of the first 4 parameters, as these are in registers anyway. I use these registers directly.

Note that `_a1`, `_b1`, `_oldIn1` and `_oldIn2` are passed in *XMM0* - *XMM3* respectively, so the first part of your code overwrites some of these registers. For instance, loading *XMM3* with `_b1` would overwrite `_oldIn2`. The same happens with *XMM2*, which holds `_oldIn1`.

It would make sense to rearrange your register usage so you don't have to use memory storage as an inbetween.

IOW, try something like (untested):

```
asm
        MOVDDUP XMM0,XMM0
        MOVDDUP XMM1,XMM1

        MOVLPD  XMM4,[Sample1]
        MOVHPD  XMM4,[Sample2]
        MULPD   XMM4,XMM0

        // etc...
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. And I was not sure If MOVDUP was ok. The big problem is that I use some old offline documents to learn SSE (http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/).

Comment: Try the official documents from AMD or Intel. They can be downloaded for free, as a number of .pdfs.

Comment: To load in two halves, start with `movsd` to instead of `movlpd`.  Only use `movlpd` if you *want* to merge into the old value and have a dependency on it.  Also the upper half might as well be `movlps` to save one byte of code size.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi there's a debugger pane ("FPU") which shows the SSE registers. So if you feed your filter some non-zero values you should be able to find where the silent output comes from.